# Can I rescue any data if one of two drives in LVM failed?

Tags: lvm, data-recovery, raid, scientific-linux

I have a Scientific Linus 6.7 box that serves some applications on our network. The person who set it up is no longer around. This morning machine stopped booting. There are two HDD's and they both show up in BIOS. If I put another HDD in, it boots fine.

I ran Ubuntu from another drive and Gparted shows the original drives are LVM2. I installed LVM and can see that they were configured to be used as one logical drive of combined capacity.

My hunch is that one of the drives failed. Can I rescue any data?

Comment: If it was a contiguous logical volume, you can retrieve what got written on the healthy drive. If it was striped (RAID0), it's all gone. (making this a comment because I can't tell you how to rebuild the array)

Comment: If Gparted is showing you both drives, they haven't failed. What happens when the machine boots? Where does it get stuck, are any messages displayed on the screen? What does Gparted show? What doe the commands `pvs`, `vgs` and `lvs` (in Ubuntu as root) show?

Answer (score 0):

Since it does still show up in BIOS, you could try to restore data with `vgcfgrestore <disk-name>`. Check out symptom 2 of this [guide](https://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/appnote/19386.html) and see if it can solve your problem